Why does read block after select in Python?
It is understood that in exceptional circumstances, a read may block after select(2) declares that data is available for reading for something like a network socket, where checksum failures or other buffer manipulations may cause data to be discarded between select and read.
However, I would not expect that to happen for a Python program when dealing only with standard pipes.
Consider the following:
with subprocess.Popen(["openssl", "speed"], text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as process:
    #  Something weird is going on. `fd.read()` below blocks even if `select` declares
    #  that there is data available. The `set_blocking` calls below partially help this,
    #  but now there is a strange delay at program start.
    os.set_blocking(process.stdout.fileno(), False)
    os.set_blocking(process.stderr.fileno(), False)

    buffer = StringIO()
    while process.poll() is None:
        rfds, _, _ = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [], [])
        for fd in rfds:
            if fd == process.stdout:
                chunk = fd.read()
                if DEBUG:
                    sys.stdout.write(chunk)
                buffer.write(chunk)
            elif fd == process.stderr:
                sys.stdout.write(fd.read())

I would expect this to work without the set_blocking calls, but it doesn't. I have also tried with standard binary streams (text=False) and the results are the same.
Why is read blocking when select says it shouldn't?

read() with no arguments reads to EOF in Python. But even outside of Python, wouldn’t the only guaranteed non-blocking read without O_NONBLOCK be a read of size 1?

@Ry- That's typically fine. The standard usage of read (at least in UNIX) is to continually read however many bytes are available in a loop until you arrive at a desired length or hit some other condition. The fact that only a single byte is guaranteed is inconsequential.

That’s not what I meant. You said you expect it to work even in blocking mode. select will return even if only one byte is available; if you request a read for more than one byte in this situation, it will block. (Reading one byte at a time should work, but is very inefficient.) So blocking mode not being an effective choice here isn’t a thing that’s exclusive to Python.

Note that openssl speed outputs exclusively to stderr.

I think your problem is that you're not specifying a size in your calls to read(). From the documentation:
 |  read(self, size=-1, /)
 |      Read and return up to n bytes.
 |
 |      If the size argument is omitted, None, or negative, read and
 |      return all data until EOF.

By not specifying a read size, the read() method will keep reading until EOF (so it will block indefinitely).
If we write your code like this instead:
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import select

with subprocess.Popen(
    ["openssl", "speed"], text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
) as process:
    os.set_blocking(process.stdout.fileno(), False)
    os.set_blocking(process.stderr.fileno(), False)

    while process.poll() is None:
        rfds, _, _ = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [], [])
        for fd in rfds:
            chunk = fd.read(1024)
            sys.stdout.write(chunk)
            sys.stdout.flush()

Then we see "live" output from openssl speed:
Doing md5 ops for 3s on 16 size blocks: 19116296 md5 ops in 2.99s
Doing md5 ops for 3s on 64 size blocks: 13388928 md5 ops in 3.00s
Doing md5 ops for 3s on 256 size blocks: 7106066 md5 ops in 2.99s
.
.
.


Interesting. I didn't know Python deviated from the semantics of the mostly universal read syscall. However, unlike write, I believe only a single byte is guaranteed so read(1024) may still block.

I guess it deviates it the sense that it allows you to call read() without providing a byte acount  (the read() syscall requires that you provide a byte count when reading), but I think the behavior of that extension is clearly documented. I'll update the answer if I can find some explicit behavior about read() on blocking sockets when there is less data available than requested. My experience is that read() simply returns fewer bytes than request and does not block, but I can't swear to it.
